# Non-parametric tests to compare conditionally independent groups

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, conditional-independence

I want to compare two groups using the Mann Whitney U test (also known as the Wilcoxon rank sum test) per this description: https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704_nonparametric/bs704_nonparametric4.html
My issue is that the two groups are conditionally independent but not independent. Is this test valid?

Comment: I suspect the U test needs independence in the two samples because it is rank based. If the samples are not independent then a rank could be induced by whatever makes them dependent and therefore invalidate the test which assumes that differences in rank are due to differences in distribution only.

Comment: The test, being a permutation test, relies on *exchangeability* of the group labels under $H_0$. Independence (and the null being true) would normally give you that. If you can otherwise demonstrate exchangeability of the group labels under $H_0$ then the test will still have the correct significance level. This works for a narrow sort of dependence (and I expect won't apply here). Can you make the form of the conditional independence you mention explicit?

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for your response. Specifically I am developing a model that ranks a group of samples in some order. I want to compare my model (Model A) against a Model B that aims to do the same thing. The models are not nested so we cannot compare them via a chi squared test. For various reasons I also cannot do cross-validation. I trained the models on a training set and have a held out test set. Originally I created a 1000 boostrap sets from the test set and got the Model A and Model B results.

Comment: @Glen_b My Model A does do better than Model B on the bootstrap set. But my issue is that the confidence intervals overlap. Therefore I was wondering if I did a Wilcoxon test (which would show that Model A does better than Model consistently on each of the bootstrap samples), if that would help with reinforcing that Model A is better. The set of bootstrap samples is the same for Model A and Model B. However, the samples within the bootstrap set are not independent of one another but rather they are conditionally independent (as each boostrap set was drawn from the same underlying population)

Comment: I'd recommend putting this information in your question,  though additional information may be needed.  At the least it sounds like your performance (how is it measured?) values for each bootstrap set would  be paired